# Why do I get NoSuchElementException even though I am catching it in cucumber stepdefinition?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, bdd

```
@When("^user clicks linkedin button of the first news item$")
    public void user_clicks_linkedin_button_of_the_first_news_item()
    {
        try
        {
            firstSocialShareElement = driver.findElement(By.className("social-share-linkedin"));
            if(firstSocialShareElement!=null && firstSocialShareElement.isDisplayed())
            {
                firstSocialShareElement.click();
            }
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: can we see the html of the page you are trying to click? (preferably a url)

Comment: It doesn't have any element as of now. that news item data is dynamic, there are scenarios that there wont be even one which is the case now and thats why I am getting the exception but its not getting caught and it shows up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a simple case of class name conflict.

Since i didn't specify the full qualified name of the exception as `org.openqa.selenium. NoSuchElementException`

It was considering it to be `java.util. NoSuchElementException`

and hence the exception was not getting caught.

Now the problem is resolved.

```
      try
        {
            firstSocialShareElement = driver.findElement(By.className("social-share-linkedin"));
            if(firstSocialShareElement!=null && firstSocialShareElement.isDisplayed())
            {
                firstSocialShareElement.click();
            }
        }
        catch(org.openqa.selenium. NoSuchElementException e)
        {

        }
```